# What is the equivalent of mb_convert_encoding in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, utf-8

Currently I do the following in PHP to convert from UTF-8 to ASCII, but with the UTF-8 characters as HTML encoded. For instance, the German ß character would be converted to `&szlig;`.

`$sData = mb_convert_encoding($sData, 'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8');`

In GCC C++ on Linux, what is the equivalent way to do this?

Actually, I can also take an alternative form like, instead of `&szlig;`, the `&#xNNN;` format will do.

Comment: There's no such standard function in C++. You'll need some library that speaks HTML.

Comment: @Volomike: Deleted that comment.

Comment: @KerrekSB Perhaps someone knows of a class or function that's shared on the web for this. A hyperlink to that would help me.

Comment: Do you actually need `&szlig;` or will `&#xNNN;` do?

Comment: @MatsPetersson `&#xNNN;` will do. I'll revise my post.

Comment: So, the code I wrote here may help: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534494/convert-from-utf-8-to-unicode-c
(the function `utf8_to_unicode` converts a set of bytes to an `int` value).